# Get all document from all folder and subfolder from document library sharepoint powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, powershell

I'm making a script in Powershell for get all the documents within a document library and its folders and subfolders, I'm doing something like this:

```
$DocumentLibary = "TestDocuments"
$LibLists = "test"
function GetFiles ($Lists)
{


    foreach ($file in $Lists.RootFolder.Files)
    {   
        Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
    }

#Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
     foreach ($SubFolder in $lists.RootFolder.SubFolders)
        {
            if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
            {  
                Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
                GetFiles ($Subfolder)

            }
        }
}

$rootWeb = $clientContext.Web
$LibLists = $rootWeb.lists.getByTitle($DocumentLibary)
$clientContext.Load($rootWeb)
$clientContext.load($LibLists)

$clientContext.Load($LibLists.RootFolder)
$clientContext.Load($LibLists.RootFolder.Files)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
GetFiles $LibLists
```

But with this I only get the documents in the root of the document library.

Any idea ? what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dude, replace your script with this.

```
$DocumentLibary = "TestDocuments"
$LibLists = "test"

$rootWeb = $clientContext.Web
$LibLists = $rootWeb.lists.getByTitle($DocumentLibary)
$clientContext.Load($rootWeb)
$clientContext.load($LibLists)

$q = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$q.ViewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">0</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID" /></OrderBy></Query></View>'
$items = $LibLists.GetItems($q)
$ctx.Load($items)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($item in $items)
{
    #Your code to iterate items here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function ProcessAllSubfolders($folderCollection)
    {
        foreach ($folder in $folderCollection)
        {
            if ($folder.Subfolders.Count -gt 0)
            {
                ProcessAllSubfolders($folder.SubFolders)
            }

            ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
        }
    }

    # main

    foreach ($folder in $RootFolder.SubFolders)
    {
        if ($folder.Name.StartsWith("a"))
        {
            if ($folder.Subfolders.Count -gt 0)
            {
                ProcessAllSubfolders($folder.SubFolders)
            }

            ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
        }
}
```

OR

Go to the document library or list.
Open Explorer View of the respective document library.
Drag & Drop the folder from library to local drive OR Select the folder -> right click -> copy, then paste it on the local drive.