# PowerShell: Modify Content Type in specific sub folder

Tags: powershell, content-type

I am using the following power shell script:

http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/change-content-type-set-on-files-in.html

To change the content type from the standard "document" content type to a new one in a document library, This works fine but i have a requirement that i only need to apply a certain document type to documents and documents in sub folders which are only in a certain root folder in the document library.

This has stump me on how you tell in to only look in a certain folder, I belive is something along this line: I need to tell the powershell script to select the folder like this, but what ever i try does not seem to work.

list["Documentlibaryname"].RootFolder.SubFolders["Folderwhicholdtheitemiwanttochange"]

but then i thought it might not work like that i might have to do some looping of folder names like in the follow link to select the correct folder:

[Get all document from all folder and subfolder from document library sharepoint powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211165/get-all-document-from-all-folder-and-subfolder-from-document-library-sharepoint/211167)

Answer (score 0):

I Found out that each item hold the full url under this value:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms196386(v%3Doffice.14)

So I used the following IF statement to match the start of the file url path to match what folder i want to apply the content type to:

if ($_.File -like "$nameofdoclibrary/$Folder_root/*"){

$_["ContentTypeId"] = $newCTID

}

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following line of code works for me In Power Shell after a ton of work
$F.Properties["ContentTypeId"]=$ProjectFolder.Id.ToString()
$F is the folder from $Web.GetFolder.
$ProjectFolder is the new ContentType

Full code below.
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue
Start-SPAssignment –Global
$Site = "http://myreallykewlsite"
$File = "TheFolderToUpdateinSite"
 $Title="NewTitlebyRodney"

$ContentType="ProjectFolder"

$web = Get-SPWeb $Site
$FolderType = $web.AvailableContentTypes["Folder"]
$ProjectFolder = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType($FolderType, $web.ContentTypes, $ContentType)
$FolderType.Group = "Folder Content Types"
$web.ContentTypes.Add($ProjectFolder)
$web.Fields.Add("ProjectInfo","Text",$false)
$ProjectInfo =$web.Fields.GetField("ProjectInfo")
$ProjectInfo.Group="Folder Content Types"

## step 9

$FieldLink = New-OBject Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($ProjectInfo)
$ProjectFolder.FieldLinks.Add($FieldLink)
$ProjectFolder.Update()
Stop-SPAssignment –Global

## Get the documents Library

$List = $web.Lists["Documents"]

## update the library to allow managment of content types then addd the contenttype to the library.

$List.ContentTypesEnabled =$True
$List.Update()

$List.ContentTypes.Add($ProjectFolder)
$List.Update()

## add the field to the Default View.

$D=$List.DefaultView
$D.ViewFields.Add($ProjectInfo)
$D.Update()

## Get the List Item by its Title field value

## $ListItem = $List.Items | Where {$_["Name"] -eq $File}

#foreach($_ in $ListItem){

## Set "Department" column value

## ok now to change the type from "Folder" to "ProjectFolder"

## and add the Project Title and Info information

$F=$Web.GetFolder($Site + "/Shared Documents/" + $File)
    #fojoadsfjadslfj  here is your error Rodney
    #$F.Item.File.CheckOut()
    #$FI.CheckOut()
    $F.Properties["ContentTypeId"]=$ProjectFolder.Id.ToString()
    #$FI.CheckIn()
    $F.Update()
    $F["Project"] = $Title
    $F.Update()

## }

"Updated: " + $Site + " : " + $File + " : " + $Title