# How to find all subfolders inside a SharePoint Folder using PNP Framework

Tags: development, document-library, csom, folder, pnp

I want to find all the subfolders of a SharePoint folder using PNP framework. My current code is like this

```
            using (var cxt = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web oWebsite = cxt.Web;
            List list = oWebsite.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            cxt.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            cxt.ExecuteQuery();
            FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
        };
```

This gives me only direct descendants. But I want to get all sub folders. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550318/get-all-sub-folders-from-a-specific-sharepoint-2013-library-using-csom) & [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211165/get-all-document-from-all-folder-and-subfolder-from-document-library-sharepoint) (using `RecursiveAll` in CAML) . let me know if it helps you.

Comment: @GaneshSanapthat helped a lot, I am getting just one error at line var allFolders = folderItems.Select(i => i.Folder).ToList();

Comment: 'ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'ListItemCollection' could be found

Comment: As you have all the folders in `folderItems`. Now you can iterate over the collection using other C# methods instead of using `.Select()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solutions:

**Solution 1**:

Use [CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee543376(v=office.15)) in CSOM which will retrieve all folders in document library.

**Example**:

```
public static void GetAllFolders(List list)
{
    var ctx = list.Context;
    var folderItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
    ctx.Load(folderItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i.Folder));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Source**: [Get all sub-folders from a specific SharePoint 2013 library using CSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550318/get-all-sub-folders-from-a-specific-sharepoint-2013-library-using-csom)

**Solution 2**:

Use CAML query like below to fetch folders from document library:

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

**Source**: [Get all document from all folder and subfolder from document library sharepoint powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211165/get-all-document-from-all-folder-and-subfolder-from-document-library-sharepoint)